# Using CASE IF logic to return column WHEN a certain variable is specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic, case, case-when

Lets say for instance I have two columns A & B.

Column A contains numbers 1 - 10. Column B contains Months Jan - Oct

I need help writing logic that looks at column B and returns the value in column A that is 2 months prior. Say for instance Column B is March, I'd like to return the value for January.

I'm guessing I could use some sort of CASE logic to do so?

```
 CASE WHEN ColB = 'March' THEN (Select ColA where ColB = 'January')
```

I know the above logic is wrong, I'm trying to understand how to do this. Any ideas?

Thanks

UPDATE: This example was a very big oversimplfication... I'm running into an error when using any of the logic everyone suggested..

It should be worth adding that I have multiple cases of each data point in column A. I also have other columns in my query that are unique so I can not use a DISTINCT.

'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression"

Comment: What would you return if it were January?

Comment: I'd be fine with a NULL or I can just create a local variable to return 'Not Available'

Answer (score 0):

You were close, can be done like this (but this would return 9 null rows and one valid row)

```
SELECT
      CASE WHEN ColB = 'March' 
        THEN (Select ColA FROM tablename WHERE ColB = 'January') 
      END
FROM tablename
```

Or can be done without a `CASE` would be

```
SELECT
  (SELECT colA FROM tablename WHERE colB = 'January')
FROM tablename
WHERE colB = 'March'
```

See example of second running [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09243/2)

Answer (score 0):

you have to select the table 1st if you want to review the result , try this

```
select CASE when ColB = 'March' THEN (Select ColA From yourtable where ColB = 'January') END     
from yourtable
```

Comment: @Goat CO , it return 1 because columnA of JAN is 1. sorry not enough rep to post there

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be best served by a self JOIN:

```
SELECT a.b Month1 ,b.b Month2
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table1 b
 ON a.a = b.a+2
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbbe5/10/0)

This works for all months, but you could limit it to your example:

```
SELECT b.a
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table1 b
 ON a.a = b.a+2
WHERE a. = 'March'
```

Comment: Assuming that those are the values he has and not just example values

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a general solution.  Unfortunately, storing the month names as you are doing is not really efficient.  But you can do it with a self-join:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             (case colB
                   when 'January' then 1
                   when 'February' then 2
                   when 'March' then 3
                   when 'April' then 4
                   when 'May' then 5
                   when 'June' then 6
                   when 'July' then 7
                   when 'August' then 8
                   when 'September' then 9
                   when 'October' then 10
                   when 'November' then 11
                   when 'December' then 12
              end) as monthnum
      from t
     )
select colA,
       (select top 1 colA from t t2 where t2.monthnum = t.monthnum - 2) as ColAMinus2
from t
```